# snmpwalk: Cannot find module

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap, snmpd

I searched intensively and applied available solutions from google, all these solution did not fixed the problem. I keep getting the error messages when running the command snmpwalk on the Ubuntu OS which is using net-snmp. The following is the error messages I am getting. Can you please assist me how to address the following error messages?

Ideally, I want to do the snmpwalk on all my mibs folder  using the following command, which is not working.
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c PUBLIC 192.168.10.10 -M /my_MIB_Files/

I thought may be abc.mib is using other mib files. To remove the dependencies, I tries following solutions, but none was working:

1. Provided my mibs folder in the /etc/snmp/snmp.conf file such as: 
   mibs +/my_mibs_files/
   mibs +ALL
2. provided the +/my_mibs_files/ as an parameter with snmpwalk like: 
   snmpwalk -v2c -c PUBLIC 192.168.10.10 -M /my_mibs_files/ -m /my_mibs_files/abc.mib

I am getting the following error messages:
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c PUBLIC 192.168.10.10 -m /my_MIB_Files/abc.mib

MIB search path: /home/user/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 13 in /my_MIB_Files/abc.mib

**NEW ISSUES NOW AFTER PLACING THE MISSING MODULE IN /usr/share/snmp/mibs:**

> Attempt to define a root oid (iso): At
> line 6 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.mib
>  Bad parse of OBJECT
> IDENTIFIER: At line 6 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.mib
>  Did
> not find 'mib-2' in module SNMPv2-SMI
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON-MIB.txt)
>  Unlinked OID in RMON-MIB: rmon
> ::= { mib-2 16 }
>  Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 88 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON-MIB.txt
>  MIB search path: 
> /home/user/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
> Cannot find module (TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB): At line 15 in
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Did not find 'statistics' in
> module RMON-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'history' in module RMON-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
> Did not find 'hosts' in module RMON-MIB
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find 'matrix' in
> module RMON-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'filter' in module RMON-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
> Did not find 'etherStatsEntry' in module RMON-MIB
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'historyControlEntry' in module RMON-MIB
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'hostControlEntry' in module RMON-MIB
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'matrixControlEntry' in module RMON-MIB
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find 'filterEntry'
> in module RMON-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not
> find 'channelEntry' in module RMON-MIB
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find 'tokenRing' in
> module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'tokenRingMLStatsEntry' in module #-1
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'tokenRingPStatsEntry' in module #-1
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib)
>  Did not find
> 'ringStationControlEntry' in module #-1
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Did not find
> 'sourceRoutingStatsEntry' in module #-1
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib) 
>  Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB:
> filter2Table ::= { filter 4 } Undefined identifier: filter near line
> 5432 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Unlinked OID in
> RMON2-MIB: channel2Table ::= { filter 3 } Undefined identifier: filter
> near line 5152 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Unlinked OID
> in RMON2-MIB: historyControl2Table ::= { history 5 } Undefined
> identifier: history near line 4993 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB:
> matrixControl2Table ::= { matrix 4 } Undefined identifier: matrix near
> line 5095 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Unlinked OID in
> RMON2-MIB: hostControl2Table ::= { hosts 4 } Undefined identifier:
> hosts near line 5038 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
> Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB: tokenRingPStats2Table ::= { statistics 6 }
> Undefined identifier: statistics near line 5265 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB:
> tokenRingMLStats2Table ::= { statistics 5 } Undefined identifier:
> statistics near line 5209 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
> Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB: etherStats2Table ::= { statistics 4 }
> Undefined identifier: statistics near line 4936 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB:
> sourceRoutingStats2Table ::= { tokenRing 8 } Undefined identifier:
> tokenRing near line 5376 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
> Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB: ringStationControl2Table ::= { tokenRing 7
> } Undefined identifier: tokenRing near line 5321 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/RMON2-MIB.mib 
>  Did not find 'snmpModules' in
> module SNMPv2-SMI (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.txt)
> Unlinked OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkMIB ::= { snmpModules
> 10 } 
>  Undefined identifier: snmpModules near line 10 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.txt 
>  Did not find 'mib-2'
> in module SNMPv2-SMI
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-ADDRESS-FAMILY-NUMBERS-MIB.txt) 
> Unlinked OID in IANA-ADDRESS-FAMILY-NUMBERS-MI B:
> ianaAddressFamilyNumbers ::= { mib-2 72 } 
>  Undefined identifier:
> mib-2 near line 8 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANA-ADDRESS-FAMILY-NUMBERS-MIB.txt 
>  Did not
> find 'snmpModules' in module SNMPv2-SMI
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt) 
>  Did not find 'mib-2' in
> module SNMPv2-SMI (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt) 
>  Unlinked
> OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmp ::= { mib-2 11 } Undefined identifier: mib-2
> near line 262 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt 
>  Unlinked OID
> in SNMPv2-MIB: system ::= { mib-2 1 } 
>  Undefined identifier: mib-2
> near line 75 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt 
>  Unlinked OID
> in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpMIB ::= { snmpModules 1 } Undefined identifier:
> snmpModules near line 13 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt 
> Did not find 'mib-2' in module SNMPv2-SMI
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANAifType-MIB.txt) 
>  Unlinked OID in
> IANAifType-MIB: ianaifType ::= { mib-2 30 } Undefined identifier:
> mib-2 near line 7 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IANAifType-MIB.txt 
>  Did
> not find 'mib-2' in module SNMPv2-SMI
> (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt) 
>  Did not find 'snmpTraps' in
> module SNMPv2-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt) 
>  Unlinked OID
> in IF-MIB: interfaces ::= { mib-2 2 } 
>  Undefined identifier: mib-2
> near line 48 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt 
>  Unlinked OID in
> IF-MIB: ifMIB ::= { mib-2 31 } Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line
> 15 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt 
>  Unlinked OID in IF-MIB:
> linkUp ::= { snmpTraps 4 } Undefined identifier: snmpTraps near line
> 1118 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt 
>  Unlinked OID in IF-MIB:
> linkDown ::= { snmpTraps 3 } Undefined identifier: snmpTraps near line
> 1106 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IF-MIB.txt 
>  Cannot find module
> (LLDP-EXT-DOT1-MIB): At line 28 in /MIB_Files/fslldp.mib 
>  Cannot
> find module (LLDP-EXT-DOT3-MIB): At line 31 in /MIB_Files/fslldp.mib
>
>  Cannot find module (LLDP-V2-TC-MIB): At line 33 in
> /MIB_Files/fslldp.mib 
>  Cannot find module (LLDP-V2-MIB): At line
> 35 in /MIB_Files/fslldp.mib 
>  Did not find 'mib-2' in module
> SNMPv2-SMI (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/INET-ADDRESS-MIB.txt) 
>  Unlinked
> OID in INET-ADDRESS-MIB: inetAddressMIB ::= { mib-2 76 } Undefined
> identifier: mib-2 near line 7 of
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/INET-ADDRESS-MIB.txt 
>  Bad operator (:): At
> line 921 in /MIB_Files/fslldp.mib Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpMIBGroups ::= { snmpMIBConformance 2 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMPv2-MIB: snmpMIBCompliances ::= { snmpMIBConformance 1 } 
> Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB: sourceRoutingStats2Entry ::= {
> sourceRoutingStats2Table 1 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpBasicComplianceRev2 ::= { snmpMIBCompliances 3 } 
>  Cannot adopt
> OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpBasicCompliance ::= { snmpMIBCompliances 2 }
>
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpSetSerialNo ::= { snmpSet 1 }
> Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpPrivProtocols ::= {
> snmpFrameworkAdmin 2 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB:
> snmpAuthProtocols ::= { snmpFrameworkAdmin 1 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID
> in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpObsoleteGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups 10 } 
>  Cannot
> adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpNotificationGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups 12
> }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpWarmStartNotificationGroup
> ::= { snmpMIBGroups 11 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpBasicNotificationsGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups 7 }
>  Cannot adopt
> OID in SNMPv2-MIB: systemGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups 6 } 
>  Cannot
> adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpSetGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups 5 }
> Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpCommunityGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups
> 9 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpGroup ::= { snmpMIBGroups
> 8 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB: ringStationControlCreateTime
> ::= { ringStationControl2Entry 2 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB:
> ringStationControlDroppedFrames ::= { ringStationControl2Entry 1 }
>
>  Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB: sourceRoutingStatsCreateTime ::= {
> sourceRoutingStats2Entry 2 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB:
> sourceRoutingStatsDroppedFrames ::= { sourceRoutingStats2Entry 1 }
>
>   Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpEngine ::= {
> snmpFrameworkMIBObjects 1 } 
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpEngineMaxMessageSize ::= { snmpEngine 4 }
> Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpEngineTime ::= {
> snmpEngine 3 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB:
> snmpEngineBoots ::= { snmpEngine 2 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpEngineID ::= { snmpEngine 1 }
>  Cannot adopt
> OID in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpMIB ::= { snmpModules 1 }
>  Cannot adopt OID
> in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkMIB ::= { snmpModules 10 }
> Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkMIBConformance
> ::= { snmpFrameworkMIB 3 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB:
> snmpFrameworkMIBObjects ::= { snmpFrameworkMIB 2 }
>  Cannot adopt
> OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkAdmin ::= { snmpFrameworkMIB 1
> }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkMIBGroups
> ::= { snmpFrameworkMIBConformance 2 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkMIBCompliances ::= {
> snmpFrameworkMIBConformance 1 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB:
> ringStationControl2Table ::= { tokenRing 7 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> RMON2-MIB: sourceRoutingStats2Table ::= { tokenRing 8 }
>  Cannot
> adopt OID in SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpFrameworkMIBCompliance ::= {
> snmpFrameworkMIBCompliances 1 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpSet ::= { snmpMIBObjects 6 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpTraps ::= { snmpMIBObjects 5 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpTrap ::= { snmpMIBObjects 4 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB: snmpEngineGroup ::= { snmpFrameworkMIBGroups 1
> }
>  Cannot adopt OID in IF-MIB: linkDown ::= { snmpTraps 3 }
> Cannot adopt OID in IF-MIB: linkUp ::= { snmpTraps 4 }
>  Cannot
> adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: authenticationFailure ::= { snmpTraps 5 }
> Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: warmStart ::= { snmpTraps 2 }
> Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB: coldStart ::= { snmpTraps 1 }
> Cannot adopt OID in RMON2-MIB: ringStationControl2Entry ::= {
> ringStationControl2Table 1 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
> snmpTrapEnterprise ::= { snmpTrap 3 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMPv2-MIB: snmpTrapOID ::= { snmpTrap 1 }
>  Cannot adopt OID in
> SNMPv2-MIB: snmpMIBConformance ::= { snmpMIB 2 }
>  Cannot adopt OID
> in SNMPv2-MIB: snmpMIBObjects ::= { snmpMIB 1 }

Comment: Check if any of the modules can be found in /home/user/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp If not, find them on the internet (tons of places offer .txt format) and put them in /my_MIB_Files/. No surprise, as NET-SNMP by default only ships a few core MIB documents, but things like LLDP-* are not in there.

Comment: Thanks Lex. I placed the missing modules under "/usr/share/snmp/mibs" folder that has decreased the number of errors. However, I am encountering other errors now, see above my output.

Comment: As a MIB compiler vendor, I can only suggest that you find the right MIB documents to resolve such errors. Wrong documents can only lead to miserable errors that you cannot easily resolve. I collected some for my customers, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmppro-mib but clearly I have no idea on LLDP-* ones.

Comment: We have put many man-years into making our collection of MIBs sane. What I suggest is to start with a minimal set (ie. a success scenario), then incrementally add. The reverse direction (start from failure) usually is a big waste of time.

Answer (score 7):

The solution to the above errors is the execution of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

Comment: I would mark this as "The Solution" if I could, thank you